# Split a character string and convert to data.frame/tibble in R?

Tags: r, list, stringr

I have data that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data <- tibble(cats = c("a", "a|b |c", " b", "b| c"))
```

I want to convert this column to a list so I can unnest it and then summarize it so I can get the values of each category.

This is what I want to do, which doesn't work:

```
data %>%
 str_split(cats, "\\|") %>%
 unnest() %>%
 str_trim(cats) %>%
 count(cats)
```

My understanding from reading the error messages is that this is problematic because the `str_split` is creating a list of lists rather than a new `data.frame`/`tibble`.

So, I did this, which get's me my desired results:

```
data <- tibble(cats = str_split(data$cats, "\\|"))  %>%
 unnest()

data <- tibble(cats = str_trim(data$cats)) %>%
 count(cats)

data

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cats      n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 b         3
3 c         2
```

At this point, I'm ready to move on, but I'd like to get some idea of what I'm doing wrong to this in a pipe.

Comment: `str_split`'s first argument should be a vector. Start with `data %>% pull(cats) %>%   str_split(., "\\|") %>% ...`, for example.

Comment: @markus, when using this code ```data %>%
 pull(cats) %>%
 str_split(., "\\|") %>%
 unnest() %>%
 str_trim(cats) %>%
 count(cats)``` I get this error: ```Error in UseMethod("unnest_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_' applied to an object of class "list"
Calls: %>% ... freduce -> <Anonymous> -> unnest -> unnest.default -> unnest_
Execution halted```

Comment: Try `data %>% pull(cats) %>% str_split(., "\\|") %>% unlist() %>% str_trim(.) >%   table() %>% as_data_frame() %>% setNames(., c("col1", "col2"))`. But this is unnecessary complicated compared to @benc's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to put your `str_split` and `str_trim` functions inside a `mutate` argument like so:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(cats = str_split(cats, "\\|")) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(cats = str_trim(cats))

data <- data %>% group_by(cats) %>% summarize(n = n())

data

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cats      n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 b         3
3 c         2
```